# Create a file with the list of specific file names for a prefix passed through a different file

Tags: batch-file

I'm looking for a windows batch program which reads a list file which contains the prefix of file names and then place those matching file names into another list file. I don't know whether this is possible through windows batch commands. The following is an example i'm looking to do.

Test.lst

---

11145

11361

23567

Files in the directory C:\input

---

11145_Page1.tif

11145_Page2.tif

11361.tif

235671_Page1.tif

235671_Page2.tif

235671_Page3.tif

**Output Should be :**

### 11145.lst

11145_Page1.tif

11145_Page2.tif

### 11361.lst

11361.tif

### 23567.lst

235671_Page1.tif

235671_Page2.tif

235671_Page3.tif

Comment: you will find this much easier if you switch to powershell which comes with most versions of windows

Comment: unfortunately I don't know anything about powershell.

Comment: it is worth investing time in learning if you want to do these sorts of complex batch operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"

::
:: This line is merely setting up the files in a test environment
::
FOR %%a IN (11145_Page1.tif 11145_Page2.tif 11361.tif 235671_Page1.tif 235671_Page2.tif 12345_junk.tif 235671_Page3.tif) DO COPY NUL "%sourcedir%\%%a" >NUL 2>nul


FOR /f %%a IN (q22988667.txt) DO (
 FOR /f %%c IN ('dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\%%a*.tif"') DO ECHO(%%c)>"%destdir%\%%a.lst

GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q22988667.txt` containing your data for my testing. The very first `for 55a` line simply sets up some dummy files on my test system and has nothing to do with the core function.

It goes without saying that were you to enter `23` in addtion to `2356` in your prefix-list file then all files starting `23` would be listed in `23.lst` - including the entries in `2356.lst`.

---

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"

::
:: This line is merely setting up the files in a test environment
::
FOR %%a IN (11145_Page1.tif 11145_Page2.tif 23.tif 11361.tif 235671_Page1.tif 235671_Page2.tif 12345_junk.tif 235671_Page3.tif) DO COPY NUL "%sourcedir%\%%a" >NUL 2>nul


FOR /f %%a IN ('sort /r q22988667.txt') DO (
 (FOR /f %%c IN ('dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\%%a*.tif"') DO ECHO(%%c)>"%destdir%\%%a.lst"
 FOR /f %%c IN ('dir /b /a-d "%destdir%\%%a*.lst"') DO IF /i NOT "%%c"=="%%a.lst" (
  FINDSTR /v /x /g:"%destdir%\%%c" <"%destdir%\%%a.lst" >"%destdir%\tempfile.txt"
  MOVE /y "%destdir%\tempfile.txt" "%destdir%\%%a.lst" >NUL 
 )
)
GOTO :eof
```

Revised version.

By sorting the list of prefix-names in reverse order, the longer names are processed before any shorter line which is a truncated version of the longer line. All that's then required is that any name that appears in the longer-named `.lst` file is removed from the shorter-named `.lst` - easily accomplished with `findstr /v /x` into a tempfile and use `move` to overwrite the original shorter-named file.

Hence, `2356` will be processed first, and `23` later. In the `23` processing, the presence of `2356.lst` is detected and the contents of `2356.lst` is removed from `23.lst` via the tempfile.

Comment: It is working excellent as I asked earlier. Is there any way I can extend this to find for example to find some thing like 23.tif and 23_1.tif in the same command. so that it will not write anything which starts with 23 as mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

This is rather simplistic but gives correct results for your test case 
(should be run directly from command line):

`for /f %a in (test.lst) do dir /b %a*.tif >%a.lst`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type "test.lst"') do (
dir "c:\input\*.tif" | find "%%a" && echo %%a.lst>>New_List_File.lst || echo %%a not found)
```

That will create the file `New_List_File.lst` with the matching value.

That's an idea you can easely adapt for your problem.